# Directive to handle dynamic resizing of textareas is causing too frequent Forced Reflow

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, reflow

[image]

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="appraisal in appraisals">
    <div layout="row">
        <div layout="row" class="textareaDiv" dynamic-resize d-appraisal="appraisal">
          <textarea ng-model="appraisal.name"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div layout="row" class="textareaDiv" dynamic-resize d-appraisal="appraisal">
          <textarea ng-model="appraisal.department"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div layout="row" class="textareaDiv" dynamic-resize d-appraisal="appraisal">
          <textarea ng-model="appraisal.grade"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div layout="row" class="textareaDiv" dynamic-resize d-appraisal="appraisal">
          <textarea ng-model="appraisal.remarks"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module("MyModule").directive("dynamicResize", [dynamicResize]);

function dynamicResize() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      appraisal: "=dAppraisal"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var ngElement = angular.element(element);
      var textarea = ngElement[0].getElementsByClassName("textareaDiv")[0];

      var watchGroup = ["appraisal.name", "appraisal.department", "appraisal.grade", "appraisal.remarks"];

      bindToEventHandlers(textarea);

      scope.$watch(watchGroup, function() {
        resize(textarea);
      });

      function resize(textarea) {
        textarea.style.height = "30px";
        textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
      }

      function bindToEventHandlers(textarea) {
        textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
          resize(textarea);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My table can grow up to few hundreds of entries and should not be displayed in pagination. 
The textarea should resize automatically while user is typing too.

The number of layout reflows have affected my application's performance.

I supposed I cannot use `md-virtual-repeat` as it requires item size to be same.

Are there any suggestions to help minimize reflows and improve performance?

Comment: Do you have to support IE9 or older ?

Comment: @Julien no, I just need to support chrome..